# How to define variable so it doesn't clean my file every time I run it

Tags: python, file

I just started studying dictionaries and I encountered the following issue. I have the variable `dictionary` that is modified various times through some other functions, and every time that happens if dumps itself to a file using the pickle module (obligatory to use pickle). `dictionary` is originally defined as `dictionary = {}` so everytime I run the program it cleans the file. I thought of defining it using`pickle.load` but it really isn't working. Does anyone know how could I modify it so it loads the file and, just in case its empty it adds the empty dictionary.

Here's the part of the code that is giving me issues:

```
dictionary = {}
toys = open('toysFile','wb')
pickle.dump(dictionary,toys)
toys.close()
toysRB = open('deporte,','rb')
toysRBLoad = pickle.load(toysRB)
print(toysRB)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood the question but opening it in `ab` mode will allow you to append to the end of the file instead of overwriting.

Comment: The first thing you should do is check to see if the file exists, and if it does, read the dictionary from it.  If not, write the cleared dictionary to it.

Comment: @RufusVS how could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it

```
import pickle

dictionary = {"test": "1"}

# save to pickle file
toys = open('toysFile.pkl','ab')
pickle.dump(dictionary,toys)
toys.close()

# load pickle file
toysRB = open('toysFile.pkl','rb')
toysRBLoad = pickle.load(toysRB)

print(toysRBLoad)
```

Comment: It is working yet is not quite what I need. Dictionary starts as empty, but there are some functions where the user inputs different data, this goes to the dictionary and then the dictionary is written to the file. Sin dictionary is defined as {} it always cleans the file, I need to define dictionary in a way that this doesn't happen.

Comment: @theJohnLewis Can you show me a clearly example?

Comment: Yep, give me a second

Comment: I believe typing it is kind of difficult, is there an easier way to show you?

Comment: @theJohnLewis You can send me a file or link that i can download code.

Comment: Okay, give me a second. Is it a problem if the code is mainly in Spanish?

Comment: How can I send you a message?

Comment: @theJohnLewis yep, you can do it!

Comment: I dont' see the option to do so

Comment: @theJohnLewis You can leave a comment here!

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wWd4aJTHiF9AOej6tb5OZ51PYij2B0Fe?usp=sharing

Comment: I shared a Drive link

Comment: @theJohnLewis. Give me a second!

Comment: @theJohnLewis try my edited code in following link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GDmDWxWqv2kjuAa5Y7alZUzbJ4aZzCtz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm gettin EOFError: Ran out of input

Comment: Got it, just deleted the previous file!

Comment: @theJohnLewis yep. Have a nice day, bro!

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the file already exists, and if not, create it:

```
try:
    dictionary = pickle.load(open('toysFile",'rb'))
except Exception as e:
    dictionary = {}
    toys = open('toysFile','wb')
    pickle.dump(dictionary,toys)
```

(Untested code should work)